# UTC timezone for "date" and "time" datatypes in Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, time, azure-sql-database

I'm planning to use [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql) and [time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql) datatypes in my SQL Server 2016 Express database, which I will be deploying to an Azure SQL database in the production environment.

I know for the "datetime2" datatype, Azure SQL stores it in UTC timezone. Is this also the case for "date" and "time"? The Microsoft references (linked above), date and time's are not "Time zone offset aware and preservation".

Does this mean they are not stored in UTC time like datetime2? Do I still have to worry about converting to and from UTC time?

Comment: Sql Azure always runs in UTC timezone: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2013/07/29/manage-timezone-for-applications-on-windows-azure/

Comment: With the "time" data type the time is without time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock.

Answer (score 2):

To complement Alberto's answer, it's more a data acquisition question than a datatype question.

A datatype doesn't carry any assumption on the data. A variable registered as `time` or `date` is just a specification to the SQL query engine. It tells the engine how to physically store the data and it provides a valid set of operations that can be performed on the data. As a result, a `time` variable does not assume any time zone per se. It can contain UTC time, PST time or any time zone you want. Same for a `date` variable.

Going back to your question, the need for a conversion to UTC time will depend on the data acquisition method. If you fill your table using the built-in `GETDATE()` method on Azure, the data will be UTC and the datatype will be `datatime`. To extract a `date` variable and a `time` variable, you can use the `CONVERT` operator.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Azure database always use UTC time.For that reason you should not use datetime data type. Instead you should use datetimeoffset.

You should also capture the system date using sysdatetimeoffset() instead of using getdate().

When you retrieve dates from the database tables you should then use “AT TIME ZONE” as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql).

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Comment: Thanks but I was referring to the "time" datatype. Is that stored in UTC time too?